# Create Something Like NTFS Junctions in Android 2.2

Tags: cyanogenmod, internal-storage

I'm wondering if you can create junction points on an Android device (v2.2) just like you can on a Windows computer. Basically, I want to move stuff from the /data folder on the internal memory to my sdcard, since my internal memory is almost full (due to Orbot) and I have plenty of space on my sdcard. I've already moved all my apps to the card, but apparently the /data files are still stored on memory.

I'm using a cyanogen rooted PRS-T1 ereader (very little memory). Is there a way to create junction points (or similar) using an app or the command line so that I can move those /data files to the card without creating any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link).

You can create them in any good Linux system using

```
ln -s <link_target> <link_name>
```

eg

```
ln -s /data/app /mnt/sdcard/data/app
```

or (while in /mnt/sdcard/data)

```
ln -s /data/app app
```

You will want to be careful regarding removing the SDCard - you will need to completely shutdown the device prior to removal, and the same SDCard will likely need to be in the device prior to booting.

Comment: I never remove the SDcard, so I guess its fine. 

Can I do this with the Terminal Emulator App on my device?

Comment: Yes, just use the terminal app. PS: It's a question of the file system that is used. (Practically) all native Linux and Android file systems support symbolic links. Exceptions are FAT32 and Samsungs FAT based RFS. Older Android up to version 2.2 or 2.3 used JFFS2 as default file system for /data, later versions use ext4. Some manufacturers deviated from the default though (e.g. Samsung use(d) RFS instead of JFFS2). The Sony reader very probably uses JFFS2 which allows soft links.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this... do you need to copy the files in data/app to the sdcard first before creating the symbolic link, or does the command do it for me? Also, do I need to delete the files in data/app after they are copied?

Comment: Yes. When the symbolic link exists, any attempts to read/change into that folder will instead change you into the <target> folder.